# responsive images with bootstrap - two images aligned

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML-code with bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="test-header" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p><span class="label label-default"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Parts <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="test-body" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3"> <img alt="Image1" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x300"> </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3"> <img alt="Image2" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x300"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20090/

I would like to have this a little bit different: the two images should somehow belong together (should not be in separate cols) but should be responsive if screen gets to small.

If i change the second row to the following code, i have the problem that the images align vertically on small screens, which i want to avoid.

```
<div id="test-body" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12"> <img alt="Image1" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x300"> <img alt="Image2" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x300"> </div>
</div>
```

So what i want is to have the second example, but instead of aligning vertically i would like to shrink the images when screen size reduces.

**Edit:**

Here are the images on what i want to get:

On big screens:

[image]

On small screens:

[image]

Comment: can you draw what you want?

Comment: use col-xs-12, then you can get what you need as I understood your problem.

Comment: i added a drawing on what i want to get. unfortunately col-xs-12 does not solve the problem as images get aligned vertically on small screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
img {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20097/)

Comment: goes in the right direction. But the images get too small on small screen. I'll provide with an image on what i want to get.

Comment: @Refilon I have a similar usecase. I need to make a panel with two images. One image is of size 16x16 and other 24x24. I want to divide the panel 50% for both the images and I also dont want to resize the images.

Comment: @Apoorva Make a question, and i'll try to help you too

Answer (score 0):

you need to divide the division into two.
your div must be like this

`<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
 <img src="img.jpg"/>
</div>`
`<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
<img src="img.jpg"/>
</div>`

then set your image `width` to `100%`

Check this demo https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20098/